# Confusion on how to display custom field data

Tags: custom-field

Hey I'm new to WordPress. I've looked at the codex and other topics here, I just don't get how to display my custom field, which I have set in the area under my post editor. The name is `MyField` and the value `This is my custom post text`.

Now I want to include my field into the category loop, so it shows up instead of the standard excerpt.

`<?php the_meta(); ?>` shows obviously all custom fields, that is not what I want.

I´ve tried to include `<?php get_post_custom_values('MyField'); ?>`, which changed nothing, do I have to do something with this after that like calling it? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: [**`get_post_meta()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta):

```
if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'MyField', $single=true ) ) {
    echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'MyField', $single=true );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below will help
For user meta:

```
<?php 
  $user_id = 9;
  $key = 'last_name';
  $single = true;
  $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
  echo '<p>The '. $key . ' value for user id ' . $user_id . ' is: ' . $user_last . '</p>'; 
?>
```

For Post meta:

```
<?php 
$key_1_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'key_1', true );
// check if the custom field has a value
if( ! empty( $key_1_value ) ) {
  echo $key_1_value;
} 
?>
```